# How to test methods efficiently with JUnit

Tags: java, testing, junit

My first method is simple, its just a `toString` which outputs 3 class specific fields

```
public String toString(){
    return String.format("%s/%s/%s",street,city,postcode);
}
```

In JUnit it gives me this to form the tests on, I am unsure how to do this efficiently.

```
@Test
public void testToString() {
    System.out.println("toString");
    Address instance = null;
    String expResult = "";
    String result = instance.toString();
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
    // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
    fail("The test case is a prototype.");
}
```

I have done lots of research on JUnit and understand the concept of testing but can't quite get my head around how to do it with my code. Also how would I test this method efficiently, this is a method in a subclass which is the abstract method in the parent class

```
@Override
int getDiscountRate() {
   return this.companyDiscount; 
}
```

It gives me this to test

```
@Test
public void testGetDiscountRate() {
    System.out.println("getDiscountRate");
    BusinessOrganisationDetails instance = null;
    int expResult = 0;
    int result = instance.getDiscountRate();
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
    // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
    fail("The test case is a prototype.");
}
```

Comment: As for the second part of your question concerning getDiscountRate(), we usually don't test getters/setters methods, since they're almost always generated by IDE and should not be modified.

As far as unit testing is concerned, you should definitely read about Mockito framework.

Comment: Thank you sir, I shall check out Mockito framework now

Comment: Moment please. You're testing. Efficiency isn't important. Coverage and completeness are important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks good. Of course, you need to instanciate the *instance* variables, else it will result in a NullPointerException.

Here, how it could look like in the end:

```
@Test
public void testToString() {
    System.out.println("toString");
    Address instance = new Address();
    instance.setStreet("Somestreet");
    instance.setCity("Somecity");
    instance.setPostcode("12345");
    String expResult = "SomestreetSomecity12345";
    String result = instance.toString();
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

And the other test:

```
@Test
public void testGetDiscountRate() {
    System.out.println("getDiscountRate");
    BusinessOrganisationDetails instance = new BusinessOrganisationDetails();
    instance.setCompanyDiscount(50);
    int expResult = 50;
    int result = instance.getDiscountRate();
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

Comment: ahh thats interesting. Say I have all my information like street, city and postcode placed within a textfile is there anyway I could use them to test? or is setting a random field the best way to go about it? Also when testing should I do multiple tests on one method? and if so how would I do it for a tostring method?

Comment: Not with JUnit tests. Here, you do the assertions directly in the code.

There is no general answer for your question about testing a method multiple times. It depends on what that method does. In that case, one test is sufficient. In other cases, especially when you have if/else statements in the tested methods, multiple tests are needed to get 100% test coverage of your code.

Comment: ahh brilliant, thank you man. Literally understanding this so much more now!

Comment: Good to hear! And thanks for my first ever earned reputation :D

Comment: Also I see you've edited the post and done the second method. Another person said it is not necessary to test Get and set methods?

Comment: Again, this depends a bit: If those are pure getter methods that just return the value of a field, it does not make much sense, yes. When there is some logic in the getters, you of course need to test them (but that is bad practise anyways).